# How can I delete " mark from txt file I export from excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am exporting txt file using this macro:

```
Sub txtfile()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\Tax Exemption Check Template.txt"

Set rng = Selection

Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue
Else
    Write #1, cellValue,
End If
  Next j
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

where the file is exported it contains each cell with ""
for example if the cell I selected contains:

1234, the file contains "1234"
How can I delete those ""?

Thanks,

Alon

Comment: Did you try making `cellValue` of type Integer?

Answer (score 2):

This is the behaviour of `write` when it encounters string values.

Change to `print`, E.g.

```
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Print #1, cellValue
Else
    Print #1, cellValue; ",";
End If
```

Comment: In what way? This wont output "" unless there are "" in the cells

Comment: There are no "" in the cells, Im sorry I forgot to mention that the cells conatin letters too, like - a6gjhd6

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: that it is still exporting txt file with "", even when i change it to print

Comment: `print` does not add quotes (I just tried this myself) delete the file and try again?

Comment: yes, it doesnt work for some reason. I replaced what you wrote and it didnt work..